# Double loop for in template

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

I've actually a problem with my template and my loops.
I have the same problem described here : [Double loop in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660488/double-loop-in-django-template)
I have tryed the answer but it doesn't work :/ And I don't understand the django documentation about backward relationship

I've tryed to prefetch_related and selected_related like in the link above and other search about my problem but I don't really understand what does it do.

Models :

```py
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SousCategories(models.Model): #subcategories
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.categorie.name + " " + self.name
```

View :

```py
def index(request):
    response_dict = dict()
    lst_cat = []
    lst_ss_cat = []
    for cat in Categories.objects.all():
        all_cat = dict()
        all_cat['id'] = cat.id
        all_cat['name'] = cat.name
        lst_cat.append(all_cat)
    for ss_cat in SousCategories.objects.all():
        all_ss_cat = dict()
        all_ss_cat['id'] = ss_cat.id
        all_ss_cat['name'] = ss_cat.name
        all_ss_cat['cat'] = ss_cat.categorie
        lst_ss_cat.append(all_ss_cat)
    response_dict['categorie'] = lst_cat
    response_dict['ss_cat'] = lst_ss_cat
    print(response_dict)
    return render(request, "home.html", {'cat': response_dict})
```

This view give me this (Few datas just for test) :

```
{'categorie': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'playmobil'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'deguisements'}], 'ss_cat': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'neuf', 'cat': <Categories: playmobil>}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'occasion', 'cat': <Categories: playmobil>}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'propre', 'cat': <Categories: deguisements>}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'sale', 'cat': <Categories: deguisements>}]}
```

Template :

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <nav id="sidebar">
   <div class="sidebar-header">
     <img src="{% static "logo.png" %}" alt="My image">
   </div>
   <ul class="list-unstyled components">
     <p>Categories</p>
     {% for categ in cat.categorie %}
     <li>
       <a href="#{{categ.name}}" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">{{categ.name|capfirst}}</a>
       <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="{{categ.name}}">
         {% for ssc in cat.ss_cat %}
         <li>
           <a href="#">{{ssc.name}}</a>
         </li>
         {% endfor %}
       </ul>
     </li>
     {% endfor %}
   </ul>
 </nav>
 </div>
```

The actual result is that my ul balise is empty instead of containing my subcategories.
Then if someone can explain me how backward relationship works or have the solution for my problem (I've found this doc but i'm lost : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)
PS : I use the last version of python and django

Comment: There's no reason to be doing this at all. You should loop through each category's subcategory in the template, exactly as Alasdair describes in the linked answer.

Comment: what is empty? you wrote 'my is empty'.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes i'm sure this guy have the good answer but I dont understand it :/

Comment: You would be better off just following it, then seeing what it does, rather than spending time on working out why your own code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments inline explaining what's happening with your code:

```html
     {% for cat in cat.categorie %}
         <!-- here cat is redefined as {'id': 1, 'name': 'playmobil'} the first loop -->
     <li>
       ...
       <ul>
         {% for ssc in cat.ss_cat %}
              <!-- cat.ss_cat doesn't exist: no key `ss_cat` (only 'id' or 'name') -->
              ...
         {% endfor %}
       </ul>
     </li>
     {% endfor %}
```

but as explained by the other comments and answers, even if you name the loop variable differently, you would still loop through all the sub categories each time, unrelated to the main category, so it wouldn't do what you want.

Comment: Yes your right I've made a little mistake in my names just change de first cat by cate, I send from my view the cat dict which contain categorie and ss_cat Then cat.ss_cat works if it's not in the first loop

Comment: yes but your second loop is the same for each category, it just repeats each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can access SousCategories in Category instance via `category.souscategories_set.all()`, no need to iterate over things in the view.